# Problema con RegularExpression en Data annotations

Tags: c#, mvc, regex

Hola estoy haciendo un formulario y validando con data annotations pero necesito que mi usuario no tenga espacios intermedios el problema es que mi regularexpresion no funciona, podrían ayudarme a encontrar una solución por favor.

Aquí les dejo mi expresión.

```
    [Display(Name = "Usuario")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es requerido.")]
    [RegularExpression(@"[\s], ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} no puede tener espacio en blanco")]
    [MaxLength(30, ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} solo puede contener un máximo de {1} caracteres de longitud.")]
    public string UsuarioRLogin { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solución

```
[RegularExpression(@"(\S)+", ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} no puede tener espacio en blanco")]
```

Comment: +1, aunque una explicación siempre sería de gran ayuda ;)